# how to replace null value in an array with a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array in which I need to replace all the null or blank values with a string NAN. The array is basically the state of my component.

state array looks like this:

```
[{..}]
0:
company: Array(3)
0: {comp_id: Array(1)} //this value is null 
1: {comp_name: Array(1)}
2: {comp_country: Array(1)}
```

It is formed using the code below:

```
  const output = data.filters.reduce((final, s) => {
          const values = Object.keys(s).reduce((out, o) => {

            out[o] = s[o].map(k => Object.values(k)[0]);
              return out;
          }, {});
          final = { ...final, ...values };
          return final;
        }, {});
```

The JSON string for the variable output looks like:

```
"filters":{"company":[[null],["d"],["c"]]}}
```

So, before getting it into JSON format, I need to replace the null value with a string NAN. 
How to do this? Can anybody help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using** [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = {
  "filters": {
    "company": [
      [null],
      ["d"],
      ["c"]
    ]
  }
}

const output = data.filters.company.map(arr =>
  arr.map(ele => ele === null ? 'NAN': ele)
);

console.log(output)
```

**Using** [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
const data = '{"filters":{"company":[[null],["d"],["c"]]}}'

const output = JSON.parse(data, (key, value) => value === null ? 'NAN' : value)

console.log(output)
```